# Warning messages before a PHP script runs

Tags: php, jquery, shell, alert

I have a simple little script that is merging files sourced from remote servers.

The merge operation is happening as part of a $_POST action. So when I post I want to be able to warn the user the ensuing merge action and response will take a few seconds to complete. Of course putting a js or swal warning message works after the POST.

However the warning message will not pop up until the PHP processing is all done by which time the warning is a bit pointless. I have tried numerous approaches (like JQ hiding a showing warning divs based on button clicks) but ultimately  all my attempts fall into the same trap - the PHP wants to run first and the message must follow.

Anybody got any ideas (or am I stuck with concocting a server side event routine)?

(ps I cannot change the script below.  The shell command is a pre requisite here)

```
                <?php
                if (isset($_POST['options']))//FINAL GENERATE BUTTON
                {

                //JS ALERT OR SWAL OR MODAL MESSAGE---------> "MIGHT TAKE A WHILE THIS"



                if (false!==file($attach_source))//cannot use if file_exists on a remote server poll. Use the $file() function instead
                {   
                    file_put_contents
                        (
                            $attach_dest,//destination path.filename (ON SERVER)
                            file_get_contents($attach_source)//source file 
                        );
                }
                else
                {   
                echo 'STUFF';
                }

                //MERGE...  
                    $fileArray= array($deposit_info,$attach_dest);

                //set up target path/file for merged
                    $outputName = $final_path.$front.$propertyid.".pdf";


                //ghostscript command line--does the merging then puts the 
      merged file into $outputName (off-the-shelf script)
                    $cmd = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -
    sOutputFile=$outputName ";
                    foreach($fileArray as $file) 
                        {
                        $cmd .= $file." ";                                                                  
                        }
                        $result = shell_exec($cmd);
           .............    
         }
    ?>
```

Comment: thats just not correct. Be specific. The problem is clearly outlined and it has everything to do with PHP. If you have a real solution post it. Not general comments that mean nothing to the reader please.

Comment: If you're using jQuery use `.ajaxStart()` to display the warning, then `.ajaxStop()` to remove it when done.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I think the issue is that PHP is trying to parse everything before it even gets to JS or AJAX. Could you maybe show a brief example. I just want to be sure it isn't something that will fall foul of that procedural problem.

Comment: Your PHP shouldn't run until the AJAX call is made as it should be the AJAX call which initiates the PHP.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard.  I'm not so sure he is doing an AJAX call here.  (I would, if I here him, but it seems he's doing a non-AJAX POST request).

Comment: He isn't @BareNakedCoder, but he should be instead of trying to output JS from the PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to fix this client-side in Javascript.  Using jQuery ...

```
$('#my-submit-button').click(function() {
    $('#my-warning-message').show();
    $('#my-form').submit();
});
```

Include the warning message (inside a `<div id="my-warning-message" style="display:none">`) in the HTML page from which the POST is submitted (not in the response HTML).  When your submit button is clicked (`id="my-submit-button")`), this JS fragment will execute.  It will show the warning (you may want to show it a different way) and, after it is shown, submits the form data to your PHP script.  The user will see the warning as the form data is being processed server-side by PHP.

Comment: I tried this. Same problem. As soon as you JQ submit you are into the POST actions and the PHP which wants to process first. So the message pops up after the PHP parsing which is the time delay, That is the issue Im afraid.

Comment: Ah i missed your second comment. Thank you. Let me just have a look at that more closely please.

Comment: Where is your warning message?  I'm saying include it in the first page, before the user clicks the submit button.  Keep this warning hidden (`display:none`) until the user clicks the submit button.  The `click` handler shows the warning before submitting the form.  That means the warning should be shown to the user even before the request is sent to your PHP.

Comment: No Im still not sure why you think this will work. If you post the form and we have a bunch of php actions that depend on that post, the php actions will get processed before show() which also depends on the post ie (submit(). So to late. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Remember, I'm adding this JS code to the HTML page displayed *BEFORE* the POST request is sent to PHP.  The JS code will "show" the warning just before it sends the POST request to your PHP.  As your PHP is working, the user is sitting there staring at the last HTML page display ... which because of "show" has the warning you want.

Comment: I think Jay is on the right road above BNC, But let me give this some more consideration too, Thank you

Comment: Thank you BNC. That worked well. It was the addition of the form submit () part of the answer that made the difference. Indeed PHP is now following the the alert. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

This will require you to rethink your logic a bit...

If you are using jQuery you should use the jQuery to initiate the call to the PHP script, rather than having the PHP script run and try to deliver warnings via JavaScript because the *PHP must finish running before the JavaScript* is output to the browser. Here is an example:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    // code to display warning
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    // code to remove warning when AJAX is complete
});

$(document).some_event_which_will_cause_ajax_to_run(function() {
    $var merge = $.ajax({
        url: "merge.php", // your PHP script
        method: "POST",
        data: {options: options}
    });
    merge.done(function(msg){
        // do something when the call is complete
        console.log(msg);
    });
    merge.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        $('some_container').text('AJAX failure when merging: ' + textStatus);
    });
});
```

The first two function are automatically called whenever an AJAX request is called.

Any subsequent work you need PHP to perform should also be called by an AJAX request, because (as stated) outputting JS from PHP requires the PHP to finish *before* the JS is output as PHP does not *interact* with the client as it outputs (there are ways to do this, but they stink).

Comment: Yeah that has legs. Thank you Jay. I should really have though about using ajax to drive the php script in the first place. Thank you for a well considered response. I will give it a bash within the environment Im working in and let you know how i got on with this. Thank you.

Comment: It worked Jay, Perfectly in fact. But im only allowed to select one working answer and BNC below was to be honest a bit simpler to execute in my environment. I've marked your answer up because it works brilliantly well .